# Probability scenario during mysql registration

Tags: mysql, insert

After saving the data I need to switch to the update query but I am worried about data loss.

In the following scenario, if the registration is successful and the update fails, how can you cancel the previous operation or write a scenario in this case?

```
$q1= DB::insert('INSERT INTO withdrawMoney (user,amount) VALUES (?,?)',array(1,500));
if($q1){
$q2= DB::exec('UPDATE users SET amount = amount + ? WHERE id = ?',array(500,1));
if($q2){
continue.....
}
}
```

Comment: Use a transaction to make it atomic. If the update fails, you roll back the transaction and the insert will be undone.

Comment: Any decent database tutorial should teach about transactions, they exist precisely for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Do you think such a logic would be appropriate?

```
$q1= DB::insert('INSERT INTO withdrawMoney (user,amount) VALUES (?,?)',array(1,500));
if($q1){
$q2= DB::exec('UPDATE users SET amount = amount + ? WHERE id = ?',array(500,1));
if($q2){
contine...
}else{
delete last insert bla bla
}
}
```